# What does `?{}` Represent in PowerShell

Tags: .net, windows, powershell

I'm have the following expression in `PowerShell`:

```
$oneTypes = Get-ChildItem -Path $Location -Directory


$onlyCompile = @( $BASE_A, $BASE_B, $BASE_C )
#trying figure this line  out
$oneTypes = ($oneTypes | ?{$onlyCompile -contains $_})
```

I'm not sure what the `?` and `{...}` do here? It looks like it might be a script block but I'm not sure. I'm also wondering how the pipeline comes into play on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`?` is used as a short form for `Where-Object` command and here it means filter all the objects that are in the supplied array `$onlycompile`

Answer (score 2):

The answer to the other part of your question is that `{...}` after the `?` or `Where` does indeed represent a scriptblock.  If you look at the help on Where-Object you see this:

```
-FilterScript <ScriptBlock>
    Specifies the script block that is used to filter the objects. Enclose the script block in braces ( {} ).

    The parameter name (-FilterScript) is optional.

    Required?                    true
    Position?                    1
    Default value
    Accept pipeline input?       false
    Accept wildcard characters?  false
```

The `FilterScript` parameter expects a scriptblock. It is positional so you don't have to specify `Where -FilterScript { ... }`.  It is not pipeline bound but the `InputObject` parameter is pipeline bound.  That object gets injected into the scriptblock you provide as `$_`.